# Inner join on multiple rows

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have two tables: 
acquisitions and geo. We can find an acquiror country code and a target country code in the acquisitions table. In the geo table, we can find the geographical distance between two countries. All the possible combinations are in this table (1 combination = a country_2_letter_1 and a country_2_letter_2) and have their own geographical distance (distcap). I want to update the acquisitions table with the suitable geographical distance between the country of acquiror and target. This is what I've come up with but I keep getting the error: `Unexpected end of the SQL command`

Any help?

```
 update acquisitions t
   set t.geographical_distance=
   (select s.distcap
   from
(SELECT 
distinct g.country_2_letter_1, g.country_2_letter_2, g.distcap
FROM 
   geo g
INNER JOIN 
    acquisitions z1 ON (z1.target_country_code = g.country_2_letter_2)
INNER JOIN
    acquisitions z2 ON (z2.acquiror_country_code = g.country_2_letter_1))s
WHERE 
    (t.acquiror_country_code = s.country_2_letter_1 and t.target_country_code = s.country_2_letter_2);
```

Comment: The parenthesis before "SELECT" isn't closed.  You need another closing parenthesis at end of query.

Comment: Man, unbelievable, thanks for the quick help !